# How to update account without confirming your password using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise, updates

Here is the problem: I am using omniauth-facebook with devise, and when someone logged with facebook try to update a photo or anything else, apeears an error that "password can't be blank". I am trying to solve this issue for hours and couldn't find a way, I think the best way to do it is to enable people to update account without the necessity to confirm the password. I know that devises explain how to do it here: 
 [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password) 
But it doesn't work out for me, I am new at rails and I think I am doing something wrong! Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you complete the step where you reconfigure your routes? Devise won't know to use your custom controller unless you have.

Comment: Yes! I did exactly the way on the site: devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

```
1) Create one file in config/initializers/
   for example devise_participants_without_password.rb

2) Open devise_participants_without_password.rb and put this code without any change
   module Devise
    module Models
      module Validatable
        def password_required?
         false
        end
      end
    end
   end
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I did exactly it and I still get "Current Password can't be blank" :(